# Spring Security Ajax login

Tags: ajax, authentication, spring-security

I have implemented this security proccess in my project: 
[Spring Security 3 - MVC Integration Tutorial (Part 2)](http://krams915.blogspot.com/2010/12/spring-security-mvc-integration_18.html).

My problem is that I need to turn it into an Ajax-based login.
What do I need to do in order to make this XML suitable with just returning string/JSON to the client?
I understand that the problem might be in the `form-login` tag.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/security 
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.xsd">

    <!-- This is where we configure Spring-Security  -->
    <http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" access-denied-page="/Management/auth/denied" >

        <intercept-url pattern="/Management/auth/login" access="permitAll"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/Management/main/admin" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/Management/main/common" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')"/>

        <form-login 
                login-page="/Management/auth/login" 
                authentication-failure-url="/Management/auth/login?error=true" 
                default-target-url="/Management/main/common"/>

        <logout 
                invalidate-session="true" 
                logout-success-url="/Management/auth/login" 
                logout-url="/Management/auth/logout"/>

    </http>

    <!-- Declare an authentication-manager to use a custom userDetailsService -->
    <authentication-manager>
            <authentication-provider user-service-ref="customUserDetailsService">
                    <password-encoder ref="passwordEncoder"/>
            </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

    <!-- Use a Md5 encoder since the user's passwords are stored as Md5 in the database -->
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.Md5PasswordEncoder" id="passwordEncoder"/>

    <!-- A custom service where Spring will retrieve users and their corresponding access levels  -->
    <beans:bean id="customUserDetailsService" class="com.affiliates.service.CustomUserDetailsService"/>

</beans:beans>
```

Answer (score 22):

This is an old post, but it still comes up as one of the top results for "spring security ajax login," so I figured I'd share my solution.  It follows Spring Security standards and is pretty simple to setup, the trick is to have 2 `<http>` elements in your security configuration, one for REST/Ajax and one for the rest of the app (regular HTML pages).  The order in which `<http>`'s appear is important, it has to go from more specific to more generic URLs, just like `<url-intercept>` elements inside of a `<http>`.

**Step 1: Setup Two Separate `<http>`'s**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security" 
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

    <!-- a shared request cache is required for multiple http elements -->
    <beans:bean id="requestCache" class="org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.HttpSessionRequestCache" />

    <!-- remove security from static resources to avoid going through the security filter chain -->
    <http pattern="/resources/**" security="none" />

    <!-- http config for REST services (AJAX interface) 
    =================================================== -->
    <http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" pattern="/rest/**">
        <!-- login configuration 
            login-processing-url="/rest/security/login-processing" front-end AJAX requests for authentication POST to this URL
            login-page="/rest/security/login-page" means "authentication is required"
            authentication-failure-url="/rest/security/authentication-failure" means "authentication failed, bad credentials or other security exception"
            default-target-url="/rest/security/default-target" front-end AJAX requests are redirected here after success authentication
        -->
        <form-login 
            login-processing-url="/rest/security/login-processing" 
            login-page="/rest/security/login-page" 
            authentication-failure-url="/rest/security/authentication-failure" 
            default-target-url="/rest/security/default-target" 
            always-use-default-target="true" />
        <logout logout-url="/rest/security/logout-url" />

        <!-- REST services can be secured here, will respond with JSON instead of HTML -->
        <intercept-url pattern="/rest/calendar/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />

        <!-- other REST intercept-urls go here -->

        <!-- end it with a catch all -->
        <intercept-url pattern="/rest/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />

        <!-- reference to the shared request cache -->
        <request-cache ref="requestCache"/>
    </http>

    <!-- http config for regular HTML pages
    =================================================== -->
    <http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
        <form-login 
            login-processing-url="/security/j_spring_security_check" 
            login-page="/login" 
            authentication-failure-url="/login?login_error=t" />
        <logout logout-url="/security/j_spring_security_logout" />

        <intercept-url pattern="/calendar/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />

        <!-- other intercept-urls go here -->

        <!-- in my app's case, the HTML config ends with permitting all users and requiring HTTPS
             it is always a good idea to send sensitive information like passwords over HTTPS -->
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="permitAll" requires-channel="https" />

        <!-- reference to the shared request cache -->
        <request-cache ref="requestCache"/>
    </http>

    <!-- authentication manager and other configuration go below -->
</beans:beans>
```

**Step 2: REST Authentication Controller**

```
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

import flexjson.JSONSerializer;

@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/rest/security")
public class RestAuthenticationController {

    public HttpHeaders getJsonHeaders() {
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.add("Content-Type", "application/json");
        return headers;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/login-page", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<String> apiLoginPage() {
        return new ResponseEntity<String>(getJsonHeaders(), HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/authentication-failure", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<String> apiAuthenticationFailure() {
        // return HttpStatus.OK to let your front-end know the request completed (no 401, it will cause you to go back to login again, loops, not good)
        // include some message code to indicate unsuccessful login
        return new ResponseEntity<String>("{\"success\" : false, \"message\" : \"authentication-failure\"}", getJsonHeaders(), HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/default-target", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<String> apiDefaultTarget() {
        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        // exclude/include whatever fields you need
        String userJson = new JSONSerializer().exclude("*.class", "*.password").serialize(authentication);
        return new ResponseEntity<String>(userJson, getJsonHeaders(), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

**Step 3: Submit AJAX form and process the response, required jQuery's ajaxForm library**

```
<form action="/rest/security/login-processing" method="POST">
...
</form>

$('form').ajaxForm({
    success: function(response, statusText, xhr, $form)  {
        console.log(response);
        if(response == null || response.username == null) {
            alert("authentication failure");
        } else {
            // response is JSON version of the Spring's Authentication
            alert("authentication success");
        }
    },
    error: function(response, statusText, error, $form)  { 
        if(response != null && response.message == "authentication-failure") {
            alert("authentication failure");
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Your solution seems nice but where is the controller method responding to '/rest/security/login-processing" defined?

Comment: @MichaelDeKeyser - it's mapped to UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter provided by SpringSecurity, take a look at the docs and search for 'UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter' and 'login-processing-url'.  http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.2.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/

Comment: I tried doing this via JavaConfig of Spring Security, finally had to give up and use XML ftw!

Comment: @Boon - check out this example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4912485/spring-security-ajax-login/27300215#27300215

Answer (score 5):

It depends on the implementation of your ajax-login. In any case, I guess you need to implement a custom filter. There are two good tutorials for using Spring Security with ExtJs:

[Integrating Spring Security 3 with Extjs](http://javajeedevelopment.blogspot.com/2011/02/integrating-spring-security-3-with.html)

[Integrating Spring Security with ExtJS Login Page](http://loianegroner.com/2010/02/integrating-spring-security-with-extjs-login-page)

It should work very similar for other Ajax login-forms.

Answer (score 5):

Spring is shifting away from XML based configurations and towards Java `@Configuration` classes. Below is `@Configuration` version of the setup explained in the post above ([Spring Security Ajax login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4912485/spring-security-ajax-login/16577637#16577637)).  Steps 2 & 3 remain the same, replace Step 1 with this code.  The order is once again important, more specific definitions needs to be loaded before more generic ones, use `@Order(1)` and `@Order(2)` to control that.

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.HttpSessionRequestCache;
import org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCache;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebMvcSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean(name = "requestCache")
    public RequestCache getRequestCache() {
        return new HttpSessionRequestCache();
    }

    @Configuration
    @Order(1)
    public static class ApiWebSecurityConfigurationAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

            @Autowired private RequestCache requestCache;

            @Override
            protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
                http
                    .regexMatcher("/rest.*")
                    .authorizeRequests()
                        .antMatchers("/rest/calendar/**")
                            .hasAuthority("ROLE_USER")
                        .antMatchers("/rest/**")
                            .permitAll()
                        .and()
                   .headers()
                        .xssProtection()
                        .and()
                   .logout()
                       .logoutUrl("/rest/security/logout-url")
                       .and()
                    .requestCache()
                        .requestCache(requestCache)
                        .and()
                    .formLogin()
                        .loginProcessingUrl("/rest/security/login-processing")
                        .loginPage("/rest/security/login-page")
                        .failureUrl("/rest/security/authentication-failure")
                        .defaultSuccessUrl("/rest/security/default-target", false)
                        .and()
                    .httpBasic();
           }
    }

    @Configuration
    @Order(2)
    public static class FormLoginWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Autowired private RequestCache requestCache;

       @Override
       protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
           http
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .regexMatchers("/calendar/.*")
                        .hasAuthority("ROLE_USER")
                    .regexMatchers("/.*")
                        .permitAll()
                   .and()
               .logout()
                   .logoutUrl("/security/j_spring_security_logout")
                   .and()
                .requestCache()
                    .requestCache(requestCache)
                    .and()
                .formLogin()
                    .loginProcessingUrl("/security/j_spring_security_check")
                    .loginPage("/login")
                    .failureUrl("/login?login_error=t" )
                    .and()
                .httpBasic();
       }
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web
            .ignoring()
                .antMatchers("/resources/**")
                .antMatchers("/sitemap.xml");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `HttpServletRequest.login(username,password)` to login, just like:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/login")
public class AjaxLoginController {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public String performLogin(
        @RequestParam("username") String username,
        @RequestParam("password") String password,
        HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    try {
        request.login(username,password);
        return "{\"status\": true}";
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return "{\"status\": false, \"error\": \"Bad Credentials\"}";
    }
}
```