# I need to know about the response type of $.ajax() method in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on an e-commerce site and I need google sign-on it, so when a user creates his/her shopping list and click on the add to list button. I am able to send my data through the `$.ajax()` method, so what I exactly want is when the response from ajax method come it should redirect me to Login page if the user is not logged in, else it should save my object.

Comment: Where's Java involved? Or do you mean JavaScript?

Comment: well sir the Java is involved in the servlet controller and I want to give control to servlet that it should grant only logged in user to show there list else it should redirect them to login page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the target endpoint of that .ajax() call, check your authentication, and if the user is not logged in, set the response header to - 401 Unauthorized.

Then in the .ajax() do this:

```
$.ajax(function() {
   //.. your other ajax stuff..//
   error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      // only redirect if user unauthorized - 'errorThrown' has text part of HTTP status header
      if(errorThrown == "Unauthorized") {
          window.location.href = "myloginpage.html";
      }
   }
});
```

The response header being set to 401 will trigger .ajax()'s error function, instead of the success function.

**Edit:**
Changed the error function to only redirect on Unauthorized

Also note, that if this is a cross-domain jsonp call, it won't work, as jsonp requests fail silently and don't trigger the error function

Comment: Dear Sir, but what I want is that the servlet should forward this particular page, not the script.

Comment: @AnkurJain and that's exactly what this is doing. By setting the http header in the servlet to 401, you're telling .ajax() that the user is denied. As for the redirect itself, you have to do that in the .ajax(). Remember, in an ajax call, the page itself does not do anything. Only the ajax call is active, and it's interacting with the servlet at "arm's length", for lack of a better term. The servlet has NO control over the page.

Comment: Actually Sir, the servlet doesn't forward any page i.e. not by response.sendRedirect("abc.html"), nor by RequestDispatcher also. And what I actually need to know is that what is the response type of $.ajax() method of jQuery.

Comment: @AnkurJain you mean .ajax() request type? the response type is what .ajax recieves from the servlet. The default .ajax() request type is application/x-www-form-urlencoded. it can be overriden by setting .ajax()'s 'contentType' option

Comment: @AnkurJain also, I know the servlet doesn't forward the page. It can't in a ajax call. That was my point.

Comment: Okay sir u r right, but if I point my login page from error condition in ajax method, then there may be a possibility that I could get error and in that condition also my page will be redirected to the login page.

Comment: @AnkurJain ok, I've updated the code to only redirect if the error is that the user is unauthorized

Answer (score 0):

check in your response callback function and write your programming logic that you want

```
$.ajax({
'url':location,
'type':type,
'success':function(response){
/*write here your logic*/ 
},
'error':function(){
/*you code for error handling*/
}
});
```

to redirect window by javascript use

`window.location.href = 'your location';`

Comment: Sir, I already did that but what I need is to give this control to the servlet not to the script.!

Comment: mean you want to call servlet function from success or error callback functions ?

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect to login page using window.location = 'yourlocation' in either success or error function of the response (depending upon what response you are gettig from server. If you are bringing the response  code in header 401 error function will be executed other wise success).

but i think what you would like to have is take user back to the same page after login from which he started.

If you are interrested in this, you can use spring security for this. Its very easy to integrate if you are using spring already.
If you are not using spring you might look for some alternative for the same. Following links may help you

[Spring Security Ajax login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4912485/spring-security-ajax-login)

http://java.dzone.com/articles/implementing-ajax

Comment: Okay sir u r right, but if I point my login page from error condition in ajax method, then there may be a possibility that I could get error and in that condition also my page will be redirected to the login page.

Comment: You are right but you can handle this stuff easily in jQuery depending upon the error message. You can refer to jQuery ajax doc. Refer to error handler. [link](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). You have all the control over what type of error you have.

Answer (score -2):

In jquery there is .post() method found to do this. In action page you can do whatever you want.

Comment: what's the code? This doesn't get him any more than the .ajax() call he already has