# Spring Boot and security: How to extend response for 302 status code?

Tags: java, spring, http, spring-boot, oauth-2.0

**Setup:**

- Spring Boot application
- OAuth2 security
- ReactJS for UI implementation

**Use case:**

- Login to application
- open other tab with same application in same browser
- Logout from application in one of the tabs, user are redirected to Login view
- Go to first tab(user already logout and if I refresh page I will get login form) and do any action that triggers POST/PUT/PATCH request. Example of request and response below:

**Request:**

```
Request URL:http://localhost:8080/api/info
Request Method:PUT
Status Code:302 Found
Remote Address:[::1]:8080
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade
accept:application/json
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,sv;q=0.6,ru;q=0.4,uk;q=0.2,fr;q=0.2
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:66
Content-Type:application/json
Cookie:_ga=GA1.1.1868465923.1505828166; _gid=GA1.1.612220229.1507272075; session=e4oSW4Kq; prod_user_session=4d6b615f-521704; user_session=g3ggLxJDomyZ
Host:localhost:8080
mode:cors
Origin:http://localhost:8080
Pragma:no-cache
Referer:http://localhost:8080/profile
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36
```

**Response:**

```
Cache-Control:no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:0
Date:Fri, 06 Oct 2017 12:12:26 GMT
Expires:0
Location:http://localhost:8080/login
Pragma:no-cache
X-Content-Type-Options:nosniff
X-Frame-Options:DENY
X-XSS-Protection:1; mode=block
```

After this response system triggers PUT request to `http://localhost:8080/login` and fails because PUT method not allowed for `http://localhost:8080/login` request.

**Question:**

I understands that I'm getting 302 status and `Location:http://localhost:8080/login` header because I'm already logged out. I want extend response for this case with JSON body or at least ensure that for this case I will get `401 Unauthorised` status code instead of 302.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, it sounds like you need two different responses for unauthorized requests coming via a regular webpage load (`produces="text/html"`) vs an AJAX call (`produces="application/json"`). Currently your unauthorized AJAX call gets redirected to the login page which is a legit page, hence no 401 response code. Here's an example of a setup that accomplishes what you want using XML configs [Spring Security Ajax login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4912485/spring-security-ajax-login/16577637#16577637) and @Configuration config https://stackoverflow.com/a/27300215/1718213

Another option that is even more user-friendly is to use Spring's WebSocket support to signal logout events to all the tabs a given user might have open (across all devices and browsers) that would trigger each tab to redirect to the login page.